# simple rails search form not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a very simple, typical search form in rails. Input a string, and it checks a column for that model if any strings match it. A few weeks ago it was working just fine. I came back today, and suddenly doesn't work.

Here is my code. My search form:

```
<%= form_tag("/search/products", method: "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

My Controller:

```
def search
 term = params[:q]
 puts "the term is #{term}"
 @resultats = Product.search_products(term)
end
```

In my model, the search_products method:

```
  def self.search_products(search_term)
    if search_term == ""
        return []
    else
        where("name LIKE ?", "%#{search_term}")
    end
  end
```

in the controller code, the puts "the term is #{term} prints the correct term every time. So I know that is being picked up correctly. just, when i search for something, it doesn't return the correct results. Here is a screenshot from my terminal:

[image]

"Les résultats sont" in the terminal means "the results are..." and then empty, because it returns nothing. What could be wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure that you actually have records that end with 'second' (case sensitive!) In case you want to make it possible to search for the beginning of the word and be case insensitive, you should change your query into `where("name ILIKE ?", "%#{search_term}%")`

Comment: Also, since it's a parameter directly retrieved from the internet, you should probably escape it with [sanitize_sql_like](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_like)

Comment: oh maybe that is the problem. I have records that START with "second" but not that end with second. I'll create some new records and see if that is behind it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code currently searches for `LIKE '%term'` (string must end in term)

You probably need to have it search for `LIKE '%term%'` (string must contain term)

Just add a %:

```
where("name LIKE ?", "%#{search_term}%")
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do lower(?) and search_term.downcase to make sure its not case sensitive